# Having trouble with this regular expression in PHP

Tags: php, expression, preg-match-all

I'm trying to run regular expression on the following string with PHP using preg_match_all function

"{{content 1}}{{content 2}}"

The result I'm looking for is array with 2 matches inside {{ and }}

Here is the expression `'/\{\{(.+)\}\}/'`

I'm suspecting that my expression is too greedy but how to make it less greedy?

Comment: Why do you need to escape the { characters in your pattern? Why can't you just say {{(.*)}} ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the ungreedy modifier `?`, like so:

```
$regex = '/\{\{.*?\}\}/';
```

New regex will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {{content 1}}
            [1] => {{content 2}}
        )

)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Just remembered another way to do this. You can just add a `U` (capital u) in the end of your regex string and result will be the same, like so:

```
$regex = '/\{\{.+\}\}/U';
```

Also, here is a useful list of [regex modifiers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the U [PCRE modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) (Ungreedy)

Answer (score -1):

Is the regular expression string in a single quote or double quote PHP string? Because if it's in a double quoted string, curly braces include variables so need to be escaped twice.

```
"/\\{\\{(.+)\\}\\}/"
```

Comment: It's in single quotes. Anyway just figured it out `'/\{\{(.+?)\}\}/'` Thanks